# maxHistory tag not working with log4j2 xml

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

```
<maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
```

I want to delete a log file that is over some number of days old in log4j2 xml so for that I was using maxHistory tag defined above and giving it a value of 30 days. But the following tags seems to be invalid and showing the following error.

Policies contains an invalid element or attribute "maxHistory

Any thoughts why this property is not working.

```
    <RollingFile name="AppFile"
                 fileName="/app/logs/test.log"
                 filePattern="/app/logs/archive/test-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}-%i.log">
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>%d [%t] %p %c - %m%n</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"
                                       modulate="true" />
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="500 MB" />
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10" />
    </RollingFile>
</Appenders>

<Loggers>

    <Logger name="com" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="AppFile" />
    </Logger>

    <Root level = "info">
        <AppenderRef ref = "CONSOLE" />
    </Root>

</Loggers>
```

Comment: yes, it is filename-log4j2.xml

Comment: You need to show your whole config file.

Comment: xml added to the question

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a custom delete action:

```xml
<RollingFile ... >
  ...
  <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        <Delete basePath="${baseDir}" maxDepth="2">
          <IfLastModified age="30d" />
        </Delete>
  </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
</RollingFile>
```

See https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#CustomDeleteOnRollover for full documentation.

Comment: Here it means that the log file above 30 days will be removed. What is maxDepth mean here ?

Comment: That's just how deep to look under ${baseDir} to look for files to delete. Not always necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I guess there is no chance to recover these files using this method. For recovering purpose do we have some approach and one more thing that it's final that maxHistory is not applicable to log4j2 right ?

Comment: `maxHistory` is not a log4j2 config tag -- I think it might be a logback tag. What do you mean by recovering these files? Do you mean recovering them after they've been deleted?

Comment: yes, just incase we require them.

Comment: You could write a `ScriptCondition` which copied the files somewhere else, but could you just recover old log files from your normal backups?

Comment: I have just gone through this http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#TimeBasedRollingPolicy In this Rolling policy also there is maxProperty but don't whether it is used or not

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the first answer, DefaultRolloverStrategy also provides a max field whose description is given below which helps you achieve deleting older logs.

```
<DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10" />
```

max : The maximum value of the counter. Once this values is reached older archives will be deleted on subsequent rollovers. The default value is 7.

Here counter corresponds to %i which is given in file-pattern and through this counter parameter deletion happens.

```
filePattern="/app/logs/archive/test-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}-%i.log">
```

The above answer which uses `<Delete>` helps to give you more control of what files are deleted, but the documentation also points to use the `<Delete>`  with care.

For more info https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html