# Log4j2 delete older logs so capacity will not exceed X amount of files, with timestamp on the file name

Tags: java, log4j2

I am looking for a way to delete older rolled-over files so the capacity of compressed will not exceed 100 files.
I was able to achieve it only daily, so as long as the day does not change, I will always have 100  rolled-over files but when the day change I will have another 100 files so in 5 days I will have 500 instead of 100.
from what I could find online it is because I have timestamped the files with `yyyy-MM-dd`.
I would like to keep the name of the files timestamped with `yyyy-MM-dd` but still achieve having only 100 files at all times.

My log4j2 config xml file is:

```xml
        <RollingFile name="RollingFileMarket"
                     fileName="logs/app.log"
                     filePattern="logs/app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}-%i.log.gz"
                     ignoreExceptions="true"
                     immediateFlush="false"
                     append="true"
                     createOnDemand="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m %ex %map{} %n"/>
            <Policies>
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="50 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="100"/>
        </RollingFile>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [maxHistory tag not working with log4j2 xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69309654/maxhistory-tag-not-working-with-log4j2-xml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On [Logback](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html) you can have a `maxHistory` tag, but on Log4j2 you have to write a custom retention policy as outlined in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69309878/11478354), for example using [`IfAccumulatedFileCount`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#DeleteIfAccumulatedFileCount).